# ORA-01031 Missing priviledges for updating table using synonym

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm aware that there's a couple of these questions out there, but none of the solutions helped me.

I have user A and user B. Due to the structure of things, I have a table *A.blacklist* that I need user *B* to access. I've created a synonym so that user B can just call "SELECT * FROM blacklist", no issues there.

However I seem to be missing privileges to call "UPDATE blacklist SET..." with user B.

When the database is set up with a script, a role called Dev is created and assigned all sorts of privileges (that I will list below for readability) which are in turn granted to the users A, B, ... and so forth:

```
create user A identified by A default tablespace USERS temporary tablespace TEMP;
grant CONNECT, RESOURCE, Dev to A;
grant unlimited tablespace to A;
```

After that, there's another set of grants for sys privileges:

```
grant SELECT on SYS.V_$DATABASE to A;
grant SELECT on SYS.V_$PARAMETER to A;
grant EXECUTE on SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO to A;
```

What is the correct syntax to (ideally) grant user B writing access on A.blacklist only? I'm new to oracle DB, so I am unsure if there's a different privilege I have to fulfill because I am accessing a table across users.

Granted privileges that every user (A, B, ...) has:

```
CREATE USER
CREATE TRIGGER
DEBUG CONNECT SESSION
CREATE SEQUENCE
SELECT ANY SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
SELECT ANY TABLE
CREATE ANY PROCEDURE
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM
DROP USER
EXECUTE ANY
CREATE SYNONYM
CREATE VIEW
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM
CREATE ROLE
CREATE ANY TABLE
CREATE SESSION
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE
CREATE DATABASE LINK
ALTER SESSION
```

Comment: `grant update on a.blacklist to B`. Or if you need delete and insert and others as well, `grant all on a.blacklist to B`

Comment: By the way, I strongly suggest you immediately revoke `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE`, `DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM` and `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` from your users. These are veyr dangerous privileges. The former can be used to bypass nearly all Oracle security, and the later ones can be used to redirect unsuspecting users and apps to alternate data or capture their data on inserts. In general, never give `...ANY...` (or `...PUBLIC...`) privs unless you carefully think it through. About the only one that is okay in some cases is `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`, but even that should only be given where truly needed.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Seeing as the set-up was made by someone else, I will inform the team about security risks. Thanks!

Comment: I would also revoke create user, drop user, and create role. These are highly sensitive, elevated privileges that should be reserved for DBAs in almost all cases. I'd think twice about create database link, too... Database permissions to perform DDL, DML or execute procedures should always be explicit, not implicit, even in development environments.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by user Paul W, the solution is:

```
grant update on a.blacklist to B
```

That was too simple to figure out I guess, haha.